FPS struggling, in python GUI with Tkinter
For a project for uni, i have to make a GUI that show some telemetry data and video feed of a self-made drone. But for some reason i have problems with the FPS of my video feed. The code snippet below shows my function that receives the video frames from a socket. When i calculate my fps, it is very very volatile. I think it is due to these lines: self.video_label.image.paste(image) self.video_label.config(image=photo). What should i do? How do i improve it or fix it?
def receive_video_frames(self):
    while self.imp_started == 0:
        time.sleep(1)
    startup_signal = "1"
    self.tcp_video_socket.sendall(startup_signal.encode())
    print("startup_signal is sent")
    video_tuning_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.tune_video)
    video_tuning_thread.start()

    start_time = time.time()

    data, addr = self.video_udp_socket.recvfrom(10000000)  # Adjust buffer size as needed
    image_cv2 = cv2.imdecode(np.frombuffer(data, dtype=np.uint8), cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
    image_cv2 = cv2.resize(image_cv2, (640, 360))
    image = Image.fromarray(cv2.cvtColor(image_cv2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
    photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=image)
    self.video_label.config(image=photo)
    self.video_label.image = photo

    start_average = time.time()
    end_average = time.time()
    counter = 0
    end_time = None
    while True:
        try:
            average_time = end_average - start_average
            if average_time >= 1:
                self.average_FPS = counter / average_time
                counter = 0
                start_average = time.time()

            data, addr = self.video_udp_socket.recvfrom(10000000)
            counter += 1

            image_cv2 = cv2.imdecode(np.frombuffer(data, dtype=np.uint8), cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
            image_cv2 = cv2.resize(image_cv2, (640, 360))

            image = Image.fromarray(cv2.cvtColor(image_cv2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
            # Problem i think
            self.video_label.image.paste(image)
            self.video_label.config(image=photo)

            self.video_label.image = photo
            end_time_real = time.time()
            self.FPS = 1 / (end_time_real - start_time)
        except Exception as e:
            print("Error opening video frame:", e)
            pass

I timed every part of my code and i think the problem is due to two lines:
`self.video_label.image.paste(image), self.video_label.config(image=photo)`.

How do i fix it?

tkinter is very slow. Making a good video player using tkinter is practically impossible. I recommend looking at other GUI libraries or using something like VCL that can be embedded in a tkinter frame.

Perhaps this answer will be helpful for you.
